# I don't find my provisioning profile in the code signing panel in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Normally, i should see my provisioning profile in the list here:
[image]

Why i am not getting it please?

Comment: Have you developed on this machine before? Is the certificate for it still in your keychain?  Did it perhaps expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the WWDR intermediate certificate downloaded. Your developer profile is specific to your machine. So if you set it up on an old machine, you'll need to do it again.

You can take a look and see if somethings wrong by going to the organizer (Window->Organizer). Click the device tab. On the side click on Provisioning Profiles. Profiles that are bad will have a red or yellow banner with an explanation.

Comment: The provisioning profile i had in window->Organizer has the value `unknown` in the `Portal Team`, does this mean it's ok?

Comment: Likely it doesn't. Something didn't get set up right. The newer versions of xcode auto generate a provisioning profile for you. You can regenerate this profile by making sure the "Automatic Device Provisioning" check box is selected in that same provisioning window and then hitting refresh. It should ask you to log in. User the apple id your developer account is linked to. If that doesn't work, I would start from scratch to reset up your developer profile on this computer.

Comment: Ok, can you please clarify this to me: am i allowed to create as much provisioning profile as i want? can i start from scratch? is there any restriction from Apple?

Comment: If there is a limit, it's a large one. You can also delete them. So don't worry. This provisioning stuff is tricky. Once you get the hang of it, you'll start seeing where these mistakes are coming from. But, it sounds like the developer account on your machine isn't set up right.

Answer (score 5):

(For Xcode 4.x) Select the `teams tab` in the Organizer, then click on the `refresh` button in the bottom right corner. The organizer will automatically download all the certificates, keys and profiles for you.

Actually I found it a good idea to click this button every time I change something on provisioning portal.

Of course it does not help if you mistype something on the provisioning portal or in info.plist (bundle identifiers etc)